# Enabling Amazon S3 bucket versioning

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to enable bucket versioning using the .net amazon sdk. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a specific method that can be called to enabled this in the SDK.

Comment: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_SetBucketVersioningRequest.htm